# How to implement sudo su in Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I have `sudo` access to `oracle` user being non_root user (say `guest_admin` user).  I need to login as `oracle` user to run some steps but my ruby script is failing at the very first step i.e., sudoing as oracle. Below is the piece of code.

```
require "java"
require "highline/import"
require "rubygems"
require 'rvm/capistrano'

curr =  File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
$LOAD_PATH << curr  unless $LOAD_PATH.include? curr

system "sudo su - oracle"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ruby test.rb

$rvm_path (/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm) does not exist.
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 171: __rvm_teardown: command not found
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

Can somebody help me fixing this? It's a show-stopper for me right now.

I tried to move `require 'rvm/capistrano'` at the end of the file but that dint help much.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your RVM configuration is broken.

Comment: @Adrian - Thank you for the quick response. I spent some time to see if rvm_path is set correctly and if it is included in the path variable. But still getting the same error. Is there any other way I can run `sudo su - oracle` without using `rvm-capistrano`?